# Suggest laptops for students

Tags: laptop

Under 
 - RS. 40,000
 - core i5 8th gen
 - branded laptop
 - only for study purpose browing and learning 
 For online courses

Comment: Should we know the meaning of RS? Maybe USD or EURO will be more understandable.

Comment: In India money is ref in rupee

Comment: Near to 500 euro

Comment: Can you tell us what kinds of online courses you'll be taking? Why do you specifically need an 8th gen i5? Do you have a screen size preference? Prefer thin/light/portable or larger/more performance?

Comment: Sry for later update, 1)some of the programming languages  (2)spe i 5 ,8th gen for best performance (3)screen size I do prefer bcoz as i use it for learning

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On criterias from the question (almost) any notebook in this price category will be fine for you.

But you can check for example HP Elitebook 840 G2, Lenovo IdeaPad Slim. At least in European market it is hard to find i5 for 500 euro. Actually you do not need i5 to watch training videos and browse.